# Using argdo with set with vim

Tags: vim, args, tabstop

I'm attempting to run the command "set tabstop=4" and then "retab" on multiple files.

I have gotten to point of getting my arglist like so

```
args ~/workspace/**/*.java
```

and I can see this work well when I'm just viewing the files using the args command. Now when I'm trying to run the "set tabstop=4" command on it, I'm just not able to get the correct combination of this. Ive tried

```
argdo "set tabstop=4"
```

and then

```
argdo "update"
```

but it never seems to apply the updates and I'm sure there are updates since I can go to one of the files individually and run the command and it changes the file. I've tried different combinations like

```
argdo execute "set tabstop=4"
```

and it just never seems to do anything. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: how about "argdo retab"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The syntax of `:argdo` (as per the `:help`) is

> ```
> :argdo[!] {cmd}
> ```

No quoting is involved. To execute multiple commands in one go, just separate them with `|`:

```
:argdo set tabstop=4 | retab | update
```

Comment: So I tried doing this, and it does updates to the files - but for some reason when I view the file individually in vim (the indentation has been changed from the argdo command), it didn't have the same effect as just doing set tabstop=4 to the file i.e once I run that command and then after that, I go to a file individually and run "set tabstop=4" it is changed once again.

Comment: The `:retab` command is tricky, you probably need to pass a number (`:retab 8`) to make it have any effect, maybe also add `!` when the original file uses spaces for indentation. Better find the right command on a single buffer, and only then apply via `:argdo`.

Comment: So if I go to a file that I can is messed up with indentation, I just do a :set tabstop=4 and see everything fit into place, so I'm sure that command works perfectly per file, but now I've tried :argdo set tabstop=4 | update and its still just not the same effect (it seems to have added a much larger number for the tabstop)

Comment: Actually I did a retab 8 as you suggested, I think I need to mess around with this as you said

Comment: `:set tabstop=...` just changes the amount of space that Vim displays for a Tab character; it doesn't change the file itself! Only `:retab` does that!

Comment: Ah I see. I was following - http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Converting_tabs_to_spaces
where it said "To change all the existing tab characters to match the current tab settings, use retab", so I was under the impression that it wasn't really required to change the file. Thanks!